# Javascript: How to store a declared function in a variable?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm learning Javascript and wondering if it's possible to store a declared function in a variable to be used later?

For context,

```
function add(a, b) {
   return a + b;
}

var addTogether = _.partial(add, 1);

doSomething() // returns a promise that resolves to a 2
  .then(addTogether); // expect to return 3
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why, does that not work?

Comment: var addTogether = add. bind(null, 1);

Comment: @netchkin that's the same as `_.partial`.

Comment: How can you return from a promise?

Comment: Change `add` so it uses `console.log(a+b)` and you should see that it works as desired. Returning from a promise doesn't do anything because the promise executes asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Add = function (a, b)
{
    return a + b;
}

var result = Add (2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Functions ARE data in JavaScript.

```
var foo = function(a, b) {
   return a + b;
}
```

Is perfectly legitimate.

```js
    function add(a, b) {
       return a + b;
    }

    var foo = add;
    
    console.log(foo(5,10));
    console.log(add(10, 20));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ES6 syntax to store anonymous functions in constants, like so:

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
const addOne = a => add(a, 1);

console.log(add(5, 10)); // 15
console.log(addOne(5));  // 6
```